# How to pass a member of class to another member of another class

Tags: c++, class, parameters

I have a problem. I have two classes and I need to pass the member of one as a parameter to another member of the other class, like this:

```
class A{
public:
      int functionA(string x);
.
.
.};
```

And

```
class B{
public:
    void functionB( /*here would go functionA*/);
.
.
.
};
```

This is how `functionB(...)` would look.

```
void B::functionB( /*functionA*/){
string x = generateString();
functionA(x);
.
.
.
}
```

How could I do that? I tried with `function<int(string)>& fun` but looks like that is not intended when there are classes. I also tried `functionB(int(aClass::*func)(string),aClass& a)` but same result as before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you 100% want to pass a function? You could pass a reference to the class and then call a method on it. If you really want to callback on a function pointer please confirm. If you want to use a method could you specify which c++ standard you are using? This might help in directing answers a bit. Thanks

Comment: I just want to be able to use  `functionB` on `functionA` the most efficient way. Im using c++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C++11 or higher, you can do this with a lambda:

```
class A
{
public:
    void functionA(const std::string& x)
    {
        // do something with string
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void functionB(const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& lambda)
    {
        lambda("test");
    }
};
```

And when you call it, you would do:

```
A a;
B b;
b.functionB([&a] (string x) { a.functionA(x); });
```

A complete demo is here: http://cpp.sh/5w6ng

Comment: Are you sure this would work, considering that i want that the parameter of `functionA` would be the string generated inside of `functionB` ?

Comment: @Capie, yes, it should work fine. Check out the example link I posted for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried with function& fun but looks like that is not intended when there are classes.

Looks like you tried wrong way, it works just fine:

```
class A {
public:
     void foo(std::string str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
     A a;
     std::function<void(std::string)> f = std::bind( &A::foo, &a, std::placeholders::_1 );
     f("test");
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/JIcom7)